# free Firebug-like tool for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, debugging, firebug

Is there a free tool I can use to inspect a silverlight app?

I know it's not html but there has to be something, right?

Comment: +1, yeah, there should be something like firebug. I was just worrying today about one element in my xaml.

Comment: What do you want to find out?

Comment: nothing specific right now... but I'm (kinda) used to firebug and now that I'm entering the silverlight world it feels like there's something missing

Comment: As a developer you have access to various design tools (Expression Blend for example) that you use to layout your pages. The layout is fluid, but not as fluid as HTML/CSS.

Comment: yes, that's design time, right? I want something for runtime debugging... and Silverlight 5 is not aout yet ;)

Comment: Try this tool - https://aginspector.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only one I know of is [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/). However, it is not free.

Comment: There is a free version/mode for SL Spy.

Comment: Recently I found this neat Silverlight Inspector. It doesn't cover all the possible uses but at least it's free & opensource.

https://github.com/epascales/SilverlightInspector

Answer (score 1):

I found this page while google-ing for a "WPF firebug like tool". I then found [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It works very well and is open source. As mentioned, it is a WPF rather than a Silverlight oriented tool, but since both are closely related and google links to this page when searching for a WPF oriented tool, I post this answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler2 @ http://www.fiddler2.com/

Comment: This will only debug n/w traffic, but does fill a hold SL Spy doesn't fill.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains have made [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) available. It is currently free (hope it stays that way, unlike .Net Reflector).

It will also convert Silverlight DLLs all the way back to readable source code! I have tried it on several SL projects and it works like a charm.

**Note: as of the time of this writing it still gets a couple of things wrong: string concatenations and event handlers generate the wrong code.*

Comment: And the reason for the pointless downvote is? DotPeek is still available and works just fine. Downvotes without comments are just poop without the dog :P